# Capybara(with Cucumber and Selenium) attach_file redirecting after uploading

Tags: file-upload, selenium, cucumber, capybara

Here is my x_steps.rb:

```
Given "I upload an image" do
attach_file('file','image.png')
click_button "Save Changes"
end
```

And the line from my x.feature file:

```
When I go to Upload page
When I upload an image
```

And here is the html for the input form/field

```
<form action="/en/upload/" method="post" id="main_form">
...
<input multiple="multiple" type="file name="file">
...
</form>
```

Upon running Selenium goes to the Upload page and may or may not attach the file. But the line attach_file('file','image.png') causes a redirect to file:///image.png. Then the click_button causes an error because there is no button on the page anymore.

Does anyone know whats going on? 
Also are there any alternatives to uploading files?

Comment: type="file 
Is missing a closing " quote.